# codeigniter .htaccess work but cant find controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using CI version 3.1.0

and inside my httacces file like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

and i have change my config file to `$config['index_page'] = ''`

i'ts work but CI seem cant find controller that request fromm url.
example `localhost/site/index.php/welcome` its work as expected, but when request it with `localhost/site/welcome` i got 404 page not found.

Comment: I found this,may help  https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

Comment: not work to... its give me error object not found...

Comment: Please note:  the name of your "httacces" file should be spelled `htaccess`... this is very important.

Comment: @sparky sorry it's just a typo... but my htaccess file is actually .htacccess

Comment: can you give us the full vhost config file ?

Comment: @B.Assem do u mean this file? http://pastebin.com/DhCMpxHE

Comment: *"it's just a typo... but my htaccess file is actually .htacccess"* ~ I'll bet you also have a spelling error someplace in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try replacing the last line with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It depends a bit on the hosting, too I've noticed so this might not work. Is mod_rewrite or equivalent enabled?

If your application is running inside the directory /site/, what did you put in $config['base_url']?

Comment: $config['base_url']='' and my site just running on localhost. my otherproject with previous ci can run well with that mod. i don't understand what happened really

Comment: is it running on localhost or on localhost/site? maybe try `$protocol = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$config['base_url'] = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: none... none of them work. i am just tryng everyting combination in htaccess folder. better leave them and start new project with latest codeigniter... and viola it's work...

Answer (score 0):

If you already follow this: [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/6054930), you need to set the `AllowOverride` directive to `all` in the path where your app is located. It is necessary because you are using an , `.htaccess` file. [More](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

> When this directive is set to None and AllowOverrideList is set to
>   None, .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server
>   will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.

**Remember:**

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access
>   to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down
>   your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a
>   .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the
>   same effect with better performance.

It is an developer recommendation: [Here is](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/howto/htaccess.html).