# Codeigniter : Remove index.php after subdomain in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

My current Url look like this :

```
http://www.example.com/testdesign/index.php/tasks
```

And I need it to redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/testdesign/tasks
```

My codeignitor root .htaccess file contains

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
   RewriteRule (.?)index\.php/(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

mod_rewrite is enabled on my apache server.

In my config file :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

when I run it from the localhost,it shows me like this:

```
http://www.example.com/tasks
```

But I want to remove index.php only not subdomain.

I know it might be a very small problem, but I'm unable to find the error.

Would you please give me proper suggestion about it?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should read this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/41364059/6054930](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41364059/6054930).

Comment: @ShutUpMagda, I already read this document and apply same but not working.

Comment: I've also noticed that using `site_url ()` instead of `base_url ()` is one of the causes of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testdesign

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Prevents user access to the application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

It works even if you did not configure your uri_protocol and base_url.

Comment: where you place your .htaccess file?

Comment: We put .htaccess file in root directory like this :  /application /system index.php  .htaccess

Comment: Just put it inside testdesign folder only. Don't change .htaccess file inside the application and system folder.

Comment: Just try it.. It will work I used that in all of my codeigniter projects

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. In your `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
   RewriteRule (.?)index\.php/(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/testdesign$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

OR

Set `$config['base_url']='http://www.example.com/testdesign/'`

Then
 Run `www.example.com/testdesign/tasks`

Comment: @hikamt, not working and get return url like this: www.example.com/tasks

Comment: if you set base_url. in htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: not working yet, still getting same response like this: www.example.com/tasks

Comment: I need to remove only index.php not subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `base_url()` instead of `site_url()`. See,  even when your rewrite configutarion is correctly setted, if you are using `site_url()` the *index.php* file will be included.

See more in the docs: [site_urlr()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=site_url#site_url), [base_url()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=site_url#base_url)

You also should leave blank the *index_page* config in your *config/config.php*

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: In my config file, It already blank index_page like this :$config['index_page'] = ' ';

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code to your .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```